# What is the purpose of the Tilda operator in this code?

Tags: data-science

Here is a code to find IQR in a dataset

> cols = ['M01AB', 'M01AE', 'N02BA', 'N02BE', 'N05B', 'N05C', 'R03', 'R06']
> Q1 = df[cols].quantile(0.25)
> Q3 = df[cols].quantile(0.75)
> IQR = Q3 - Q1
>
> df[**~**((df[cols] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df[cols] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]

I am unable to understand the use of the Tilda operator in the last line of this code

Not able to understand the use case of the tilda operator in this code

Comment: in this case it is a logical "not",  i.e. reverses true/false of the result of the expression (...).any()

Comment: As to me, the question is understood, you don't have to repeat yourself